# Многопоточный перебор массива

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте. Есть следующий код, который загружает файл со словами в массив, допустим, содержание файла такое:

`Привет
Пока
Магазин
Телефон
Монитор
.... // и т.д. Очень много слов`

Нужно сделать потоки для этого кода. Я пока не разобрался, как.

```
class Test
{

    static string Text;
    static string[] ReadFile;
    static int Threads;

    static void Main()
    {

        Console.Write("Введите слово которое необходимо проверить: ");
        Text = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Введите количество потоков: ");
        Threads = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        ReadFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("slova.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < Threads; i++) // ну типо потоки запускаем
        {
            (new Thread(new ThreadStart(Slova))).Start();
        }
    }

    static void Slova()
    {

       for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.Length; i++)
       {
            if (ReadFile[i] == Text)
            {
              Console.Write("Слово " + Text + " успешно найдено в файле " + ReadFile);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что этот код находит строку в файле и сверяет её с переменной `Text` столько раз, сколько установлено потоков, то есть если потоков 50, то он возьмет первую строку из файла и проверит её 50 раз, далее вторую и так далее, и сообщение о нахождении строки тоже 50 раз.

Можно сделать в место `for`

```
foreach (string textline in ReadFile) { .. } // тоже самое будет
```

Как это исправить? Чтобы потоки хорошо работали. Я не очень разбираюсь в C#. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запускаете на каждую итерацию цикла новый поток. Вот и получается 50 потоков.
Используйте готовый мультипотоковый цикл.

```
    Parallel.For(0, length, i =>
    {
       // Тело цикла.
    });
```

подробней о [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx)

Или разделите цикл на N частей по длине и в каждой создайте поток. Получите N-поточный цикл.

Comment: можете написать пример с Parallel.For ? я новичок не совсем понимаю :)

Comment: Возможно так:

    Parallel.For(0, ReadFile.length, i =>
    {
       if (ReadFile[i] == Text)
            {
              Console.Write("Слово " + Text + " успешно найдено в файле " );
            }
    });

Comment: я уже разобрался но не могу подключить System.Diagnostics, в NET 3.5,4 этого просто нету.... стоит VS 2010

Comment: Parallel.For из System.Threading.Tasks

для System.Diagnostics создавайте новую тему :)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ :)

Comment: Обязательно разбивайте большой массив на N частей. Каждый поток работает со своей частью.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163329.aspx). Удобная вещь особенно для многопоточной обработки данных.
Вот еще одна интересная [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/net/135942/) пэтой теме.